# I added coyote time to my jump in my 2d platformer(where you can jump shortly after jumping off the ledge), but it's not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

All the settings are there and the code seems correct to me, but it's just not working.
This is the code that involves coyote time:

```
[SerializeField, Range(0f, 0.3f)] private float _coyoteTime = 0.2f;

private float coyoteCounter

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    onGround = ground.GetOnGround();
    velocity = body.velocity;

    if(onGround && body.velocity.y == 0)
    {
        jumpPhase = 0;
        coyoteCounter = _coyoteTime;
        isJumping = false;
    }
    else
    {
        coyoteCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void JumpAction()
{
    if(coyoteCounter > 0f || jumpPhase < maxAirJumps && isJumping)
    {
        if(isJumping)
        {
            jumpPhase += 1;
        }

        jumpBufferCounter = 0;
        coyoteCounter = 0;
        jumpSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(-2f * Physics2D.gravity.y * jumpHeight);
        isJumping = true;
        if(velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            jumpSpeed = Mathf.Max(jumpSpeed - velocity.y, 0f);
        }
        velocity.y += jumpSpeed;
    }
}
```

If someone could please explain to me what is going wrong, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well. Your jump action is never called and is in your fixed update. What is a coyote time anyway? What exactly is it doing and not doing

Comment: Adding to what @BugFinder said, your code doesn't have the right closing brace, doesn't use vector2 properly (it's a value type, not reference) and doesn't set the velocity back to the `body` anywhere. Is this a true representation of your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you don't need to use fixed update for this, your ground.GetOnGround is probably filled on FixedUpdate itself. FixedUpdate is mostly useful when you are dealing with AddForce for a certain amount of time not just one frame.
Second if you are using FixedUpdate use fixedDeltaTime instead of deltaTime.

This is the barebone of the effect, you can add multi jump to the logic yourself.

```
// Will set from checking the ground contact on update
bool IsOnGround = true;
bool WasOnGround = true;
bool LedgeFall = false;
bool IsJumping = false;

bool ThereIsGroundContact()
{
   // Check if character is contact with ground with raycast or overlaps
}

void OnUpdate()
{
   IsOnGround = ThereIsGroundContact();

   if (IsOnGround && !WasOnGround)
   {
      OnLand();
   }

   // if falling from ledge
   if (!IsOnGround && WasOnGround && velocity.y <= 0) 
   {
      LedgeFall = true;
      CoyoteTimer = 0;
   }
        
   if (LedgeFall){
       CoyoteTimer += Time.deltaTime;
   }
    
   if (LedgeFall && CoyoteTimer >= _CoyoteTime){
       LedgeFall = false;
   }

   // You can process jump input here
   if ((IsOnGround || LedgeFall) && JumpInputPressed)
       IsJumping = true;

   WasOnGround = IsOnGround;
}

void OnLand()
{
   LedgeFall = false;
   IsJumping = false;
   CoyoteTimer = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).